# User's profile website links to porn

Tags: discussion, flags

This profile's https://stackoverflow.com/users/263285/kalyan 'website' link links to a porn site. Should this be flagged (yes in my opinion). If so, how?

Comment: I flagged one of his questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag any one of his questions/answers for moderator attention and provide a short explanation.

Answer (score 22):

The website link in his profile was misspelled (it said `wordpres.com` instead of `wordpress.com`)

I fixed the misspelling, and it now links to his actual blog.

Comment: Aaah, damn spammers!

Comment: +1, I approve of your moderation. A lesser diamond might have just nuked the user from orbit.

Comment: Did you see my flag?  It was the pretty one.  Flashing in pink and purple.

Comment: @Pop, I would have probably removed the URL completely.  Good eye, Robert.